# Type checked decomposable graph in Haskell

Tags: generics, haskell, types, pipeline

Let's say I'm creating a data pipeline which will process text files. I have the following types and functions:

```
data A = A deriving (Show, Typeable)
data B = B deriving (Show, Typeable)
data C = C deriving (Show, Typeable)
data D = D deriving (Show, Typeable)

step1 :: A -> B
step2 :: B -> C
step3 :: C -> D
```

For each of the functions step{1..3} below I would like to be able to do produce a new file from an existing file, doing something like:

```
interact (lines . map (show . step . read) . unlines)
```

I then want to be able to arrange them into a graph (so functions can have multiple inputs) to achieve the following:

1. I can traverse the data structure to tell which functions provide inputs to which others
2. The data structure will type check at compile time so that any invalid arrangement throws a type error.

I know how to do 1 without 2 (give them a common typeclass), and I know how to do 2 without 1 (just use (.)), but I'm not sure how to do both at once. Any ideas? TIA.

### Update

AndrewC's answer is pretty much spot on and gets me most of the way there, since I can then build the graph of metadata (names) using a Map and type check it separately at the same time, however I also need some flexible polymorphism. The example below solves this but with 2 serious caveats:

1. I'm not forced to be exhaustive in pattern matching in step4.
2. It's tedious; there could be dozens of these "BorC" style polymorphic types, which do nothing except enable polymorphism, and not even very safely (see 1). I tried to pattern match on members of a type class (`Step4Input` with instances for `B` and `C`) but that didn't work (it said `Couldn't match type B with C`).

```hs
data BorC = ItsB B | ItsC C

step4 :: BorC -> D
step4 x = case x of { ItsB b -> D; ItsC c -> D }

-- step1    step2
--    \       /
--   ItsB   ItsC
--     \   /
--     step4
```

Comment: It sounds sort of like you want to have a type-level graph; this is probably possible, but certainly going to be a _lot_ of work... Will the graph be changing at runtime, or is a static graph sufficient?

Comment: It's static; AndrewC's answer below gets me part of the way there, but there's something missing for me to be able to make a graph with it. Will update question.

Answer (score 2):

I may be misunderstanding your problem, but why not simply wrap the functions up with a name?
It seems a very straightforward approach to the situation which doesn't require a lot of messing about.

```
module NamedFunctions where

import Control.Category        -- so I can generalise (.)
import Prelude hiding ((.),id) -- don't worry, available from Category
```

Store a list of function names you've composed along with the function itself:

```
data Fn name a b = Fn {names::[name],apply:: (a -> b)}
```

When you show a function, just show what you composed to get there:

```
instance Show name => Show (Fn name a b) where
  show f = show $ names f
```

Define new versions of `(.)` and `($)`:

```
infixr 9 ...
(...) :: Fn name b c -> Fn name a b -> Fn name a c
f ... g = Fn (names f ++ names g) (apply f . apply g)

infixr 0 $$$
($$$) :: Fn name a b -> a -> b
f $$$ x = apply f x
```

and reclaim `(.)` to work on named functions

```
instance Category (Fn name) where
   (.) = (...)
   id = Fn [] id
```

You can leave functions you don't care about unnamed
so they don't contribute to the `names` list.

```
name  n f = Fn [n] f
unnamed f = Fn []  f
```

You can use whatever data you like to name each function, for example:

```
timesThree = name "(*3)" (*3)
addFour = name "(+4)" (+4)

step1 :: Fn Int A B 
step1 = name 1 undefined
step2 :: Fn Int B C 
step2 = name 2 undefined
step3 :: Fn Int C D 
step3 = name 3 undefined


*NamedFunctions> timesThree . addFour
["(*3)","(+4)"]
*NamedFunctions> timesThree . addFour $$$ 5
27
*NamedFunctions> step3.step2.step1
[3,2,1]
*NamedFunctions> step3.step2.step1 $$$ A
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

Comment: This is a great answer but it doesn't seem to allow for functions to have multiple inputs. I think I wasn't clear enough in my question, sorry about that!

Comment: @Scott I don't understand how you could use that graph other than to show possible routes from String to String. The data type `BorC` is actually a single data type which you could well have called `E`, and you have two functions, `ItsB::B->E` and `ItsC::C->E`. If you actually plan on applying the functions to data, you have to decide which sequence of functions. Any genuinely unresolved polymorphism would give an ambiguous type error, much as `show.read` would. Did you want a graph of all the possible routes?

Comment: It was for a data pipeline library. Messed around with it some more recently, what eventually gave me what I needed was building the graph in functions that close over their input types. That way I got the homogenous traversable graph, plus the possibility to assemble the graph of typed functions. I suppose the easier way would have been to just use Dynamic :).