# Show a list of functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Is there a way to `show` a list of functions in Haskell? When I try

> `ghci> let functions = [(+), (-), (*)]`
>   `ghci> functions`

GHCi says:

> `<interactive>:17:1:`
>     `No instance for (Show (Num a0 => a0 -> a0 -> a0))`
>      `arising from a use of 'print'`
>      `Possible fix:`
>       `add an instance declaration for (Show (Num a0 => a0 -> a0 -> a0))`
>       `In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it`

I'm not sure how to add an instance declaration for this. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this Haskell Wiki page: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Show_instance_for_functions

Comment: possible duplicate of [Typeclass representing functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20708677/typeclass-representing-functions)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't easily show a function. The standard answer is

```
instance Show (a -> b) where
  show _ = "<function>"

Prelude> [(+), (-), (*)]
[<function>,<function>,<function>]
```

Which lets you have a show instance but provides no useful information. This is generally true since there may be no compact way to show the effect of a function. Further, it's worth noting that while it's standard practice to consider functions un-`show`-able, if you do define that instance you'll be likely to get an overlapping instance condition as any instance like `instance (...) => Show (a -> b)` is both an orphan and *very* general. Rule of thumb should be that it's OK in application code, but dangerous in a library.

But with that out of the way, we can make much nicer functions for `instance Show (a -> b)`.

If you know that your function has a bounded input then you can do slightly better

```
-- | A type instantiates 'Universe' if 'universe' is a 
-- list of every value instantiating the type
class Universe a where
  universe :: [a]

instance Universe Bool where
  universe = [True, False]

instance (Universe a, Show a, Show b) => Show (a -> b) where
  show f = show $ map (\a -> (a, f a)) universe

Prelude> (&&)
[ (True,  [ (True,True)
          , (False,False)
          ])
, (False, [ (True,False)
          , (False,False)
          ])
]
```

Finally, we can use the `Data.Typeable` machinery to get a nicer summary `show` for functions, if that's acceptable.

```
import Data.Typeable

instance (Typeable a, Typeable b) => Show (a -> b) where
  show f = "{ Function :: " ++ (show $ typeOf f) ++ " }"

Prelude Data.Typeable> [(+), (-), (*)]
[ { Function :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer }
, { Function :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer }
, { Function :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer }
]
```

But beware that this will fail on polymorphic functions.

```
Prelude Data.Typeable> ($)

<interactive>:7:1:
    No instance for (Typeable b0) arising from a use of `print'
    The type variable `b0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance [overlap ok] Typeable ()
        -- Defined in `Data.Typeable.Internal'
      instance [overlap ok] Typeable Bool
        -- Defined in `Data.Typeable.Internal'
      instance [overlap ok] Typeable Char
        -- Defined in `Data.Typeable.Internal'
      ...plus 18 others
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it

Prelude Data.Typeable> ($) :: (() -> ()) -> () -> ()
{ Function :: (() -> ()) -> () -> () }
```

Comment: Thank you! I have a tree and only need to know where the functions are so this works for me.

Comment: I'm about to add this to the answer, but it might be valuable to just make a special show function for your tree rather that provide a global function instance. The problem is that it's really easy to get instance overlaps with `instance ... => Show (a -> b) where`.

Comment: @Borracha You should know where the functions are by the types. The type system prevents you from mixing functions and non-functions without wrapping them in some sort of constructor that allows you to discriminate what the types of its arguments were.