# Show the representation of a haskell operator

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create a instance of Show for haskell operator or functions, but I just can't figure it out how...

I tried

```
 instance (Show (+)) where
     show (+) = "+"
```

but of course, it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: `(+)` is not a type. Types can be instances but not values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show a list of functions in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848348/show-a-list-of-functions-in-haskell)

Comment: And from the possible duplicate: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Show_instance_for_functions

Comment: And from the possible duplicate of the possible duplicate: [`Data.Universe.Instances.Show`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-0.5/docs/Data-Universe-Instances-Show.html)

Comment: Yup, [Show a list of functions in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848348/show-a-list-of-functions-in-haskell) solves my problem, @DanielWagner

Answer (score 4):

This might not be what you're looking for, but it might be the closest you can get: we can always turn a typeclass signature into a concrete data type.

```
-- built it
class Num a where
  (+) :: a -> a -> a
  (*) :: a -> a -> a
  (-) :: a -> a -> a
  negate :: a -> a
  abs :: a -> a
  signum :: a -> a
  fromInteger :: Integer -> a


-- ours
data Num
  = Plus    Num Num
  | Mult    Num Num
  | Subt    Num Num
  | Neg     Num
  | Abs     Num
  | Signun  Num
  | FromInt Integer
deriving ( Show )

instance Num Num where
  (+) = Plus
  (-) = Subt
  (*) = Mult
  negate = Neg
  abs = Abs
  signum = Signum
  fromInteger = FromInt
```

And now we can use the `deriving ( Show )` bit on our `Num` data type to see expressions.

```
>>> 3 + 2 :: Num
Plus (FromInt 3) (FromInt 2)
```

But generally there's no way much simpler than this to show Haskell functions or operators. Usually once you've gotten a value of a type like `a -> b` then the best thing you can do to examine it is to feed it `a`s

```
instance Show a => Show (Bool -> a) where
  show f = "Fun { True -> " ++ show (f True) ++ ", False -> " ++ show (f False) ++ " }"

>>> id :: Bool -> Bool
Fun { True -> True, False -> False }

>>> not
Fun { True -> False, False -> True}
```